# Add OnSelect Event to KendoUI Tree

Tags: kendo-treeview

I'm trying to add the onSelect event to the following code:

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    animation:true,
    dragAndDrop:false,
            select: onSelect,

}).data("kendoTreeView");

    // onSelect function call
    function onSelect(e)  {
       kendoConsole.log("Selecting: " + this.text(e.node));
    }
```

It is not working. All I want is to select a parent node.

Answer (score 2):

If i am not wrong, you want to select a parent node of a node you selected, i have made small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/binbsr/h7MUr/6/) for you. You have to prevent (`e.preventDefault()`) the default behavior of [select](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#events-select) event. I am simply using [parent](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-parent) and [select](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#methods-select) client APIs.

Edit: Sorry, i accidentally deleted the fiddle, i have linked the working one.

Comment: The JSFiddle here appears to be broken. Can we correct this? I would like to see how you accomplished e.preventDefault()

Comment: Jsfiddle is broken. Also I need to know when you use  $(".target_").kendoDropTarget({ 
      drop: function(e) { 
 // How to append dragged node into the .target area.
        //$(".target_").append("child node text");
 alert("dropped"); 
    }
  });

Comment: @SKJQuery, Please supply some details on what you really want to do. If you want to work with treeviews only, You don't need to manually inject drag-drop framework, it supports it by default.